# How to use relative path in Mac for open internal and external file?

Tags: qgis, mac, osx, file-path

I would like my project to be portable, so I can share it without losing all the project paths. This seems not so easy and many times I have to reset all the paths when I give the project, with all the folders with rasters and shapefile to a colleague.

[image]

So I would like to know:

1. Can I set by default only relative path to the folder in which my project is (for opening raster and shapefile that QGIS can handle) and this remain relative even if I share the whole project to a colleague with a different operating system.
2. For opening an external file with `action` in `properties->Action` I use `Open file` with this action `[% "Ref" %]` where `Ref` is the attribute where I write the file path. I supposed that writing the path with  `./`  before the path (e.g. `./RASTER/test.jpg`) could be use to create a relative path but this seems not working. Why? And this however would work only in Unix like system!

I'm using QGIS 1.8.

Comment: Using ./ will only be relative to the QGIS install root so it doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: @NathanW Thanks I imagined something like that..I should try somthing else